# Unable to deploy to Bintray with Gradle

Tags: gradle, bintray

For one repository, I am suddenly getting 409 errors when I try to deploy:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bintrayUpload'.
> Could not upload to 'https://api.bintray.com/content/serenity/maven/serenity-cucumber4/1.0.24/property(class java/lang/String, map(provider(?)))/property(class java.lang.String, map(provider(?)))/property(class java.lang.String, map(provider(?)))/property(class java.lang.String, map(provider(?)))-property(class java.lang.String, map(provider(?)))-sources.jar': HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict [message:Unable to upload files: An artifact with the path 'property(class java/lang/String, map(provider(?)))/property(class java.lang.String, map(provider(?)))/property(class java.lang.String, map(provider(?)))/property(class java.lang.String, map(provider(?)))-property(class java.lang.String, map(provider(?)))-sources.jar' already exists under another version]
```

The build uses Gradle, and has been in use and working well for a few years. The same build process currently works for other similar modules.

Has anyone come across similar issues?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue yesterday,

> "property(class java/lang/String, map(provider(?)))/property(class
>   java.lang.String, map(provider(?)))/property(class java.lang.String,
>   map(provider(?)))/property(class java.lang.String,
>   map(provider(?)))-property(class java.lang.String, map(provider(?)))"

I just encouter this problem, my solution is, add this line

```
 classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.4"
```